# How to extract information from hector slam for autonomous navigation

Tags: slam, navigation, hokuyo-node, hector-slam, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I've got hector slam working with my hokuyo laser range finder. Now, I'm trying to use the information it uses to generate a map so that I can use it for navigating an aerial robot. Can someone please help me or direct me somewhere that will help me use hector slam for autonomous navigation?

Thanks!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59153/how-to-extract-information-from-hector-slam-for-autonomous-navigation/) by [hesh8](https://answers.ros.org/users/4498/hesh8/) on ROS Answers with karma: 61 on 2013-03-25

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

hector_slam outputs a standard [nav_msgs/OccupancyGrid](http://www.ros.org/doc/api/nav_msgs/html/msg/OccupancyGrid.html) message. Being "the" standard for 2D map representation, this message type is used by a lot of packages providing different functionality:

- SLAM, generating map, simutaneously
  localizing within them ([gmapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/gmapping),
  [hector_mapping](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping))
- self-localization in provided
  map ([AMCL](http://www.ros.org/wiki/amcl))
- navigation based upon map ([move_base](http://www.ros.org/wiki/move_base))
- exploring environments ([explore](http://www.ros.org/wiki/explore),
  [hector_exploration_planner](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_exploration_planner))

Note this list is not exhaustive but just a few examples off the top of my head.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2013-03-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [MhAyman](https://answers.ros.org/users/23522/mhayman/) on 2016-07-30**:
That really helps!

**Comment by [robotable](https://answers.ros.org/users/28854/robotable/) on 2016-12-20**:
This is helpful however more info on how to integrate hector slam odom info into move base, would be greatly appreciated! What are the launch files that need to be changed when pulling odometry info from hector into move base? in this case we are not using AMCL at all correct?

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The [hector_mapping node](http://www.ros.org/wiki/hector_mapping?distro=groovy#Published_Topics) publishes a `map` topic which can be subscribed to, or saved for later use using [map_server](http://ros.org/wiki/map_server).

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2013-03-25

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1